# Derive Euler angles derivative from angular velocity

Tags: rotations

I am using a robotics simulator named V-Rep. In V-Rep Euler angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ describe a rotation composed by three elemental rotations:
$$Q=R_x(\alpha) R_y(\beta) R_z(\gamma)$$

where $R_x$, $R_y$ and $R_z$ represent elemental rotations about axes $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively of the absolute reference frame.
If the angular velocity of an object, whose orientation with respect to the reference frame is described by the Euler angles above, is $\omega=[\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z]$ with respect to the reference frame, then am I right to say that $\dot \alpha=\omega_x$, $\dot \beta=\omega_y$ and $\dot \gamma=\omega_z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Euler angles are a poor choice for representing the orientation. Apart from that not all orientations can be represented it complicates the calculations.

What you instead could do is to use [quaternion representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) of orientation or use a rotation matrix. That would make the maths more easy, the relation between angular velocity and orientation is $\omega q = {1\over 2}{d\over dt}\operatorname{vec}(q)$, where $\operatorname{vec}(q)$ is the vector part of the quaternion.

Comment: @LukeHutchison Thanks for pointing that out. I've checket into the relation and corrected it (so hopefully I got it right this time)

Comment: At first squint that almost looks right; however, it probably is not correct, because quaternion differentiation does not follow the chain rule, since quaternion multiplication is not commutative. See "pure exponential derivative" here: http://www.neil.dantam.name/note/dantam-quaternion.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you have the individual Euler angles, produce three quaternions (using an axis-angle to quaternion conversion function) representing rotations of each Euler angle around each corresponding axis, and multiply the three quaternions together in the appropriate order so that they form a quaternion product that represents the same rotation as $Q$. Or if you have only the final rotation matrix, you can convert it into a quaternion using this method:

https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/

Then to calculate the angular velocities with respect to the *local* reference frame, you have to differentiate this quaternion over time. See equations (1) and (2) in the answer here:

[Converting from quaternion to angular velocity then back to quaternion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282938/converting-from-quaternion-to-angular-velocity-then-back-to-quaternion)

Or this cheat sheet might help (see "Finite Difference" and then "Logarithm" for quaternions):

http://www.neil.dantam.name/note/dantam-quaternion.pdf