# Mapping from quaternion Jacobian to geometric Jacobian

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, quaternions, jacobian

I have a Jacobian $J_{A}(q)$ which maps from a robot's joint velocities to the robot's end effector time derivative:
$$\dot{x} = J_{A}(q)\cdot \dot{q}$$

$x \in \mathbb{R}^{7\times 1}$ is the end-effector representation, where the first 3 elements are Cartesian coordinates and the remaining 4 are the orientation as a quaternion. I would like to convert my analytic Jacobian to a geometric Jacobian $J_{G}(q)$, where $\dot{x_{G}} = J_{G}(q)\cdot \dot{q}$ gives a vector $\mathbb{R}^{6\times 1}$ which is the linear velocities and angular rates of the end-effector.

From what I've seen, there exists a mapping $E$ such that $\dot{x_{G}} = E\cdot J_{A}(q)\cdot \dot{q}$.

I tried to derive $E$ and got the following result. Let $\xi = [\xi_{0}, \xi_{1}, \xi_{2},  \xi_{3}]^{T}$ be the quaternion orientation of the end-effector.
$$
E = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{3\times 3} & 0 \\
0 & 2H
\end{bmatrix}\\
H = \begin{bmatrix}
-\xi_{1} & \xi_{0} & -\xi_{3} & \xi_{2} \\
-\xi_{2} & \xi_{3} & \xi_{0} & -\xi_{1} \\
-\xi_{3} & -\xi_{2} & \xi_{1} & \xi_{0}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, when implementing this solution and comparing the end-effector linear and angular rates against the ground truth, it is incorrect for the angular rates (linear rates are okay). Am I doing something wrong here? I am confident the analytic Jacobian is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the source where I got the $H$ matrix was incorrect. I worked it out by hand using [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282938/converting-from-quaternion-to-angular-velocity-then-back-to-quaternion) and got that:
$$
E = \begin{bmatrix}
I_{3\times 3} & 0 \\
0 & -2H
\end{bmatrix}\\
H = \begin{bmatrix}
-\xi_{1} & \xi_{0} & \xi_{3} & -\xi_{2} \\
-\xi_{2} & -\xi_{3} & \xi_{0} & \xi_{1} \\
-\xi_{3} & \xi_{2} & -\xi_{1} & \xi_{0}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now the results are correct.